# I want the variables to hold only current date and time separately

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a a model class that looks like:

```
export class TimeInModel{
    //to store only date as  --mm/dd/yyy
    public date_today:Date;
    //to store time as --HH/mm/ss
    public time_in:Date;
    public check_status:boolen;
    constructor(){}
}
```

From `date_today`, I only want to pass the current date (mm/dd/yyy) and from `time_in`, only time (hh/mm/ss).

How do I go about this in the same class or in the component.

Comment: I will edit your question because your tags are off topic. But use `let today = new TimeInModel();`, then `today.date_today = new Date();` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question more thoroughly, I can provide you with this answer :

```
export class TimeInModel {
    public date_today: string; // Because Date is a timestamp
    public time_in: string; // Same cause
    public check_status: boolean;
    constructor() {
        let today = new Date();
        this.date_today = `${today.getDate()}/${today.getMonth() + 1}/${today.getYear()}`;
        this.time_in = `${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. @trichetriche Thanks!